# ARCore is not displaying the real dimensions of objects

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality, blender, arcore

I have problem with dimensions of the objects that i import in my android application. This is what i am trying to do:

1. Download 3d object (**.obj file**) (Example this chair: https://poly.google.com/view/3txPAhYeu-x )
2. Open the object with **Blender** and change its dimensions
3. Import the object in **android studio** using **sceneform plugin**

Everything is ok and no error occurs. But when i use the object in my application the size is not the same as size that i set in Blender. Objects are smaller than size set previously.

For example i downloaded the chair and set its height to 1 meter in blender. 
After importing in my application and using it, it is smaller than real 1 meter:
Link: http://prntscr.com/os9cr8

Another example where i set my chair to height 2 meters and after using it, it was around 1 meter height:
Link: http://prntscr.com/os9eie

One possible solution is to scale my objects in android studio and make them bigger so somehow i can get the "real" dimensions.
But before that i should test more examples and see if all objects can be scaled with the same number. For example that chair from example can be scaled with 2 and it will have more realistic dimensions than dimensions in examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution. The problem was that object that I was importing in my application was **.obj file** and according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) : "**OBJ** coordinates have no units..."

This means that it is up to the importing application to decide what a unit is.

After this in **Blender**, I opened my object (**.obj**), changed its dimensions and exported it as (**.fbx**) file. After importing in **android studio** everything was ok and dimensions were the same like previously set in **Blender**.